# Thick orange ProgressBar instead of thin blue one

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-theme

I am having a `ProgressBar` widget in my app and no matter what I do, it always shows as a fat orange one (2.x style) instead of thin blue (4.x style).

- Project build target is set to Google API 4.0.3 (API Level 15)
- SDK version requirements are set as follows:

  ```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
  ```
- Application theme is set to `Theme.Holo`
- The app is run on several devices and emulators (all running KitKat or other ICS-based versions)
- The progress bar itself is defined as follows:

  ```
     <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
          style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
  ```

(explicitly set theme is the latest attempt to turn it to the new style).

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`, not `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`.

And, `android:theme` should be set in `<Activity>` tag, not in a specific view.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

For the quick solution I recommend you to use a small Android library [SmoothProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)  allowing you to have a smooth and customizable horizontal indeterminate ProgressBar.

[image]

Credits: Johnkil

Comment: I'll use it as a last resort, but again, I'd like to understand why I cannot get the "standard" look-n-feel.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Belikoff FYI the lib is mocking something like Gmail pull to refresh, G+ , unlike google dev guidelines, the animations are smother like how gmail pull to refresh, many of the android dev try to mock google android dev guidelines and try to mock what google is doing for their app !